# Blob Storage Input returns null in Stream Analytics Job output query

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm beginner in Azure, I have created a Stream Analytics Job in Windows Azure. Here I'm using two Inputs in job, one is type of **Event Hub** and another is type of **Blob Storage**.

Below is the SQL Query for ASA Job (To store output in SQL Database) :

```
SELECT
    IP.DeviceId
    , IP.CaptureTime
    , IP.Value
    , [TEST-SAJ-DEMO-BLOB-Input].[DataType] AS TempVal -- Blob Storage Input
INTO
    [Test-Output-Demo] -- SQL Table to store output
FROM
    [TEST-SAJ-DEMO-Input] IP -- Event Hub Input
```

Below is JSON data in my Blob storage container (Blob Storage Input [TEST-SAJ-DEMO-BLOB-Input])

```
{"DataType":"DEMO"}
```

Everything is working fine except **[TEST-SAJ-DEMO-BLOB-Input].[DataType]** returns null instead of string 'DEMO'.

All data sent by Event Hub Input is storing into sql table and their is no error in process.

Any help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying possible changes to resolve this issue and finally it's resolved.

It was Blob Storage Input **[TEST-SAJ-DEMO-BLOB-Input]** configuration mistake, In configuration **Path Pattern** I was defined, **{date}{time}/Test_Demo.json** now I have just changed it with simply **Test_Demo.json** and it works.

So the issue was in **Path Pattern** of Blob Storage Input ...

But I'm still not clear about Path Pattern (**How 'Path Pattern' works?**), why "{date}{time}/Test_Demo.json" was not working

Answer (score 0):

Is this just an alias issue? You've used IP as the FROM alias. But then used the full source name for the data type field. I know that in T-SQL this wouldn't matter.

Try:

```
SELECT
    IP.DeviceId,
    IP.CaptureTime,
    IP.Value,
    IP.DataType AS TempVal -- Blob Storage Input
INTO
    [Test-Output-Demo] -- SQL Table to store output
FROM
    [TEST-SAJ-DEMO-Input] IP -- Event Hub Input
```

Also check the input for the stream job is set for JSON encoding.

Comment: Hey @Paul It's not alias issue, I think you little bit confuse here with input names. Here I'm selecting DeviceId, CaptureTime, Value from **[TEST-SAJ-DEMO-Input]** It's a **Event Hub Input** and I'm selecting **DataType AS TempVal** from **[TEST-SAJ-DEMO-BLOB-Input]** It's a **Blob Storage Input**. And also as you said it doesn't matter if I use full source name.